# Change text in javascript button

Tags: javascript, button, text

I've try everything I can to change this text on that button, but I cant.

It says 'load more' and I want to put it in spanish 'cargar más'.

The link is: https://chikabika.es/proyectos/
Capture about the problem: http://prntscr.com/mppm64

Did you know how to do it?

Comment: `$('#myButton').text('cargar más')`

Comment: Can you share the html/javascript code you have?

Comment: Links to external pages is not a valid case in SO please provide a complete,minimal and verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to change the text of the button, something like

```
<button id='example_id' type='button' value="exampleValue">TextButton</button>
```

And you wanna change just the "TextButton", you can do

```
$("#example_id").html('NewTextButton');
```

If you wanna change the value of the button too, you can do

```
$("#example_id").prop('value', 'New Value');
```

Comment: Hi Alesssz. Thank you. Where I can edit that 'TextButton'? Its an js script?

Comment: Buttons are declared in the HTML document. You can change it there writing it manually or via jquery. Usually you use jquery to change it through events, so if you need just to change it static, change it in the HTML